# Using a CSS id instead of class works locally but not on server with flexdashboard (and R markdown?)

Tags: css, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I recently built a flexdashboard with some additional CSS and realized that headings

- take CSS classes **and** IDs when rendering the flexdashboard locally as html
- take CSS classes **but not** IDs when accessing the .Rmd over the public server

.Rmd-file

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
css: www/style.css
---

### Heading 1 {.bgimg1}
This will show the background image locally compiled as html and on the server as .Rmd

### Heading 2 {#bgimg2}
This will show the background image locally compiled as html __but not__ on the server as .Rmd

### Heading 3 {id="bgimg2"}
This will show the background image locally compiled as html __but not__ on the server as .Rmd
```

CSS file (in www folder)

```
.bgimg1{
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/%22_Broome%22_%281294376%29.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

#bgimg2{
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/%22_Broome%22_%281294376%29.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

As I understand it, if I want to share the flexdashboard I need to share the URL of the .Rmd file and not the one of the html. Am I just doing something wrong here or is this problem due to the fact that the browser need to interpret .Rmd files instead of an html?

Comment: no, you use the .Rmd to generate the .HTML, then any modern web browser will render the HTML as long as it's hosted somewhere.

Comment: That's odd, because for example here I directly point to the .Rmd file: https://shiny.jschn.org/apc/dash.Rmd

Comment: I see that, I haven't ever had seen that before, but that's good to know